# Why aren't display-p3 colors being rendered properly?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, colors, color-space

I am trying to set the color of some text on a webpage using the display-p3 color space. However, after setting the color via CSS to something like `color(display-p3 0 1 0)`, the text simply appears as `#0f0`. And in fact, if I use the browser's built-in eyedropper tool to read the color value of the text, it returns `color(display-p3 0.46 0.99 0.3)`, which is how `#0f0` is represented in display-p3.

Is this a browser bug or am I misunderstanding something about how color spaces work? I was expecting `color(display-p3 0 1 0)` to be a more intense green than `#0f0`. I have tried this in both Safari 16.1 and Chrome 112 on my Macbook Pro, and the behavior is the same.

---

**Addendum**: I tried changing my laptop screen's color profile from "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" to "Display P3" in the system preferences, and doing so makes the eyedropper tool behave correctly in Safari. However, Chrome still seems to always clip the rendered color to `#0f0` in the current color profile.

However, what I still don't understand is that changing my screen's color profile muted a bunch of the colors on my screen, so that now there is a discernable difference between `#0f0` and `color(display-p3 0 1 0)`. But `color(display-p3 0 1 0)` in "Display P3" ***still*** looks exactly like `#0f0` in "sRGB". So am I misunderstanding how color spaces work, or is my monitor incompatible with display-p3, or is this a browser bug?

```css
:root { background: black; }
#p3-text { color: color(display-p3 0 1 0); }
#srgb-text { color: #0f0; }
#converted-text { color: color(display-p3 0.46 0.99 0.3); }
```

```html
<div id='p3-text'>
  This text is pure green in display-p3.
</div>
<div id='srgb-text'>
  This text is pure green in sRGB.
</div>
<div id='converted-text'>
  This text is pure sRGB green converted to display-p3.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your hardware support for p3? `@media (color-gamut: p3) { ... }`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan In Chrome, `window.matchMedia("(color-gamut: p3)").matches` seems to always return `true`. In Safari, the command outputs `true` if my screen's color profile is set to "Display P3", and `false` if it is set to `sRGB`. So maybe this is partially a Chrome bug?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan But I'm still confused why `color(display-p3 0 1 0)` in "Display P3" looks identical to `#0f0` in "sRGB".

Answer (score 2):

Switching your hardware display profile is not recommended.
Displays come precalibrated with a color profile specific to the device and unless you perform calibration with professional hardware and software you should stick to your precalibrated display profile.

Assigning sRGB or Display-P3, or any profile not obtained by calibrating against your device, will distort your colors. You might not notice in case your arbitrarily chosen profile happens to be a good fit. The profiles you mentioned (sRGB, Display-P3, etc.) should be embedded in e.g. images, defined in CSS etc. to let your system know how to transform the given (image) colors to your display's color space.

I can't reproduce the eye dropper's behaviour you describe.
Picking colors with an eye dropper will in general not return the color originally defined in a color managed system, because of the roundtrip/conversion from the original color space to the display color space to the desitination color space (which might be the same as the source color space). The final color obtained with the eye dropper is even likely to differ from one system/display to another, if the tool is grabbing actual screen colors and not what is sent to the system before conversion to the display profile.

A quick test on a mac with a display profile close to display-p3 gave me these results:

```css
.foo {
  background: #f00; /* eye dropper returns color(display-p3 0.91 0.2 0.14) */

  background: color(srgb 1 0 0); /* same as for #f00, which is expected because browsers default to sRGB */

  background: color(display-p3 1 0 0); /* eye dropper returns: color(display-p3 0.92 0.2 0.14) */
}
```

Media queries do not address the problem you describe, as suggested in some comments. They will help with the definition of colors, depending on your workflow, but your problem has nothing to do with sRGB or Display-P3 in the first place. It's about the fact that both of these will have to be transformed to and from your hardware's color space.

Added to original answer for further clarification:

HEX colors in browsers are interpreted as sRGB always. In your example `#0f0` should appear less "intense" than `color(display-p3 0 1 0)` on a device, if both color spaces fit into the display gamut or the system performs some sort of tone mapping to preserve the difference between both colors. Both colors could appear (close to) identical if at least the bigger gamut or both are clamped/mapped to fit into the display's gamut. So yes, the visible difference in those values is expected, but still no: tinkering with your hardware profile is not the way to go. Display-P3 is probably close to what your mac originally had set as the display profile and therefore reveals the difference, while setting sRGB as the display profile might have led to your system mapping `color(display-p3 0 1 0)` down to the closest sRGB color (`#0f0` or something close to it).

One more addition:

> But color(display-p3 0 1 0) in "Display P3" still looks exactly like #0f0 in "sRGB".

Yes this is expected as well.

1. Setting your display profile to Display-P3 and sending `(display-p3 0 1 0)` to the display will display pure green.
2. Setting your display profile to sRGB and sending `(srgb 0 1 0)` (same as `#0f0`) to the display will again result in pure green being displayed.

In both cases the source color space and display color space match exactly, so no color conversion will take place. The display will show pure green.